# JSPM bundle with relative imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, jspm

I'm working on converting an existing app to using JSPM. I really appreciate using paths relative to the baseUrl so I don't have to do this `../../../../vendor/...` nonsense but I did like being able to import from `./siblingModule` to import from something in the same part of the hierarchy. When trying to use jspm bundle that does currently use relative imports I get

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<project path + baseUrl>\siblingModule.js'
     at Error (native)
```

Is there a way to configure JSPM to use relative paths for module resolution alongside baseUrl resolution?

Ideally -

- `module/submodule` checks for any valid paths entries and then checks `baseUrl/module/submodule`
- `./module/submodule` checks in `currentPath/module/submodule`
- `/module/submodule` checks in `baseUrl/module/submodule`

As far as I can tell this isn't ambiguous, though please correct me if I'm wrong.

p.s. using jspm 0.16.45

Comment: I included the typescript tag because I'm testing bundling the compiled output of a TS app. I don't believe that will be relevant here, but just in case it is...

Answer (score 0):

The baseUrl is used to resolve paths.

You can configure mapping and paths in `config.json`, to import from these paths.

But nothing prevents you to use these kind of import:
`import module from './otherModule/file.js';`

If you have a problem using import, it is probably something wrong in your configuration.

See documentation: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md